# Word request: section of a book dealing with odd miscellaneous topics

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I vaguely remember that there's a term for a section of a book which deals in odd miscellaneous topics -- not exactly the same as "appendix". Any suggestions?

The words I can think of are all dancing around this idea: "arcana", "apocrypha", "errata".

Comment: Miscellany, miscellanea, addendum, supplement, annexure, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coleopterist for some reason neglected to mention *[addenda](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addenda#Noun)*, the plural form of *[addendum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addendum#Noun)*.  An *addendum* is  “Something to be added; especially text added as an appendix or supplement to a document”.

A *[miscellanea](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/miscellanea#Noun)* is  “A miscellaneous collection of different things; a *miscellany*”; a  *[miscellany](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/miscellany#Noun)* is  “A collection of writings on various subjects or topics; an anthology”.

The term *[apocrypha](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apocrypha)*, rather than suggesting *miscellaneous*, indicates  “of doubtful authorship or authority”, and its etymology is from Latin *apocryphus* “apocryphal”, from Ancient Greek ἀπόκρυφος (*apocruphos*, “hidden, obscure”).

*[Esoterica](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esoterica#Noun)* is indeed a well-known term, but usually refers to “things that are esoteric; things that are impractical or specialised”, moreso than “odd miscellaneous topics”.  Wiktionary uses a quote from a 2002 **Time**-magazine article (
[Luke Helder's Bad Trip](http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,1002447,00.html)) to illustrate:

> Helder was also a visionary given to muddled, passionate harangues on immortality, astral projection and other esoterica.

Comment: thanks, that helps. Is "esoterica" a well-known term? that's not the word I remember hearing but it seems to be the right meaning.

Comment: @JasonS, yes, well-known, but more connotation of obscure than misc.; see edit

Answer (score 0):

A *glossary* is sometimes used to explain terms, words or phrases used in the book that may need further explanation:

From Oxford English Dictionary:

> glossary, n.1
>
> A collection of glosses; a list with explanations of abstruse, antiquated, dialectal, or technical terms; a partial dictionary.